# Getting Joomla to be more verbose about errors

Tags: joomla-3.6, error-reporting

I'm having problems with a third party component and I'm trying to debug the issue. I get a failure with:

```
An error has occurred.
0 Cannot access protected property UsersModelUser::$name
```

but I'd like to know the file and line where this is happening.

I have error reporting set to development, but I'm not seeing the full PHP error/stack trace, with all its useful information. Is this logged to a file somewhere or is there other logging I need to enable?

Comment: Go to System information and see what level error reporting it is showing there.  Sometimes hosting settings will override Joomla global configuration

Answer (score 2):

Setting the error reporting to the maximum level is a good idea. But if Joomla cached those errors, you need to turn on the debug mode as well. This will reveal more details about the error you encounter.